# Upper bound of the number of oscillatory sequences

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics

Let $$A_n=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_n):x_i \in [q] \text{ for } i \in [n], x_1 < x_2, x_2 > x_3, x_3 < x_4, \cdots , (-1)^{n}x_{n-1} < (-1)^{n} x_n\}.$$ What is the cardinality of $A_n$?

I have 2 observations. First, let $$B_n=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_n):x_i \in [q] \text{ for } i \in [n], x_1 \leq \frac{q}{2}, x_2 > \frac{q}{2}, x_3 \leq \frac{q}{2}, \cdots\}.$$ We have $B_n \subset A_n$, so $|A_n| \geq |B_n| \geq (\frac{q}{2}-1)^n$.

Second, let $\boldsymbol{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_n)$ be a uniform random  variable in $\mathbb{F}_q^n$, and event $E_i$ represents $(-1)^{i+1}x_i<(-1)^{i+1}x_{i+1}$. We have $$Pr(E_i)=\frac{1}{2}, Pr(\boldsymbol{x}\in A_n)=Pr(E_1 E_2 \cdots E_{n-1}).$$ If $E_i$'s were independent, then $Pr(\boldsymbol{x}\in A_n)=(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$, i.e. $|A_n| = (\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}q^{n}$. However, $E_i$'s are not independent.

**My question is**, can we find an upper bound of $|A_n|$? Say, can we prove $|A_n| \leq (\frac{3}{4})^{n-1}q^{n}$?

Comment: Have you checked to see whether these numbers are enumerated at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, oeis.org?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, for $q \ge 2$ the sequence $|A_n|, n = 2, 3, \ldots$ seems to correspond to the 3rd, 4th, ... entries in the $(q-1)$th row of [A050447](https://oeis.org/A050447). I haven't proved this, but there's probably an easy bijection.

Comment: The special case $q=n$ (so, permutations of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ that go up, down, up, down,...) is, I think, tabulated, with much information, at https://oeis.org/A000111

Comment: @GerryMyerson, different problem. Other than the constraints between $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ this problem doesn't prohibit $x_i = x_j$.

Comment: @Peter, oops! Bye....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the terminology of Chapter 3 of *Enumerative Combinatorics*,
vol. 1, second ed., you are asking for the value of the strict order
polynomial of the zigzag poset $Z_n$ at $q$ (see Exercise
3.66). Equivalently, it is equal to $(-1)^n\Omega_{Z_n}(-q)$, where
$\Omega_{Z_n}$ is the ordinary order polynomial. The number of linear
extensions of $Z_n$ is the Euler number $E_n$. It follows that for
fixed $n$, $A_n \sim \frac{E_n}{n!}  q^n$. Moreover, it is well known
that $\frac{E_n}{n!}  \sim 2\left( \frac{2}{\pi}\right)^{n+1}$.

Comment: Unproven, but empirically for fixed $q$ we have a linear recurrence with char. poly. $$\sum_{i=0}^{q-1} (-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{i+1}{2} \right\rfloor} \binom{\left\lfloor \frac{q+i-1}{2} \right\rfloor}i x^{q-1-i}$$ and the largest root seems to tend to $\frac{2q-1}{\pi}$, so that $|A_n| \sim O(1) \left(\frac{2q-1}{\pi}\right)^n$. In particular, I think we have $|A_n| \ll \left(\frac{4q - 1}{2\pi}\right)^n$, suggesting that the double-$\sim$ means that the estimate $\frac 4\pi \left(\frac {2q}\pi\right)^{n}$ isn't tight.

Comment: Let $G_q(x)=1+\sum_{n\geq 0}A_nx^{n+1}$. By the solution to Exercise 3.66 we have the recurrence $G_{q+2}(x) = (2-x^2-G_q(x))^{-1}$ with initial conditions $G_1(x)=1(1-x)$ and $G_2(x)=1/(1-x-x^2)$. Moreover, $G_{q+1}(x) = (1+G_q(x))/(3-x^2-G_q(x))$.

Comment: Not quite. That has an out-by-one error in the indexing of $q$ and doesn't take into account the special case $A_1 = [q]$. $G_2 = \frac{1+x^2-x^3}{1-x}$, $G_{q+1} = \frac{1 + 2x^2 + (1-x^2)G_q}{3 - G_q}$ fits the data for small $q, n$.